# intercept request start and end in Vaadin 14 (Flow) with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using `vaadin-spring-boot-starter` for integration of Vaadin Framework 14 and Spring Boot.

I would like to override the `requestStart` and `requestEnd` methods of the `SpringServlet` class to do the following things:

- put stuff such as the current route / view path and current user ID into the SLF4J MDC in order to include it in each logging statement
- log the duration of the request

In Vaadin 8 there was a `SpringVaadinServlet` class which I could replace by simply annotating my custom subclass with `@SpringComponent("vaadinServlet")`.

This approach no longer works.  The `vaadin-spring` integration contains `SpringBootConfiguration` which contains a direct call to the `SpringServlet` constructor:

```java
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<SpringServlet> servletRegistrationBean() {
    String mapping = configurationProperties.getUrlMapping();
    Map<String, String> initParameters = new HashMap<>();
    boolean rootMapping = RootMappedCondition.isRootMapping(mapping);
    if (rootMapping) {
        mapping = VaadinServletConfiguration.VAADIN_SERVLET_MAPPING;
        initParameters.put(Constants.SERVLET_PARAMETER_PUSH_URL,
                VaadinMVCWebAppInitializer
                        .makeContextRelative(mapping.replace("*", "")));
    }
    ServletRegistrationBean<SpringServlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(
            new SpringServlet(context, rootMapping), mapping); // <-- HERE
    registration.setInitParameters(initParameters);
    registration.setAsyncSupported(configurationProperties.isAsyncSupported());
    registration.setName(
            ClassUtils.getShortNameAsProperty(SpringServlet.class));
    return registration;
}
```

They should use a conditional bean here so we could replace it, but unfortunately they're not.

Just adding a custom `ServletRegistrationBean` with a copy of the above code (but the constructor call substituted with my own) doesn't work, even with `@Primary`.

So is there a better way to do what I want than to exclude the whole vaadin-spring autoconfiguration and copy everything in my own configuration bean?  It works but I have to check if everything's still OK after each vaadin-spring upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [`VaadinServiceInitListener`](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/advanced/tutorial-service-init-listener.html) through which you can add a custom request handler. Alternatively you could use a [`Filter`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter).

Comment: Adding a request handler is useless for this case, since 1) I would need to ensure my handler comes first, before the regular request handling kicks in and 2) I need to hook into the end of the request as wel, so after all handlers have executed.

Comment: A `Filter` might work though I'm not sure if I'd have access to the current UI (or a UI scoped bean) which I'll need to get some of the info I need to log.  Also, I don't want to process requests for static resources etc., just real Vaadin UI requests.

Comment: It is still possible to extend VaadinServlet and override service method. If you do not know exactly what to do, it is recipe of getting things go sour. But, yes that is the path. I am still inclined to think that in normal applications there should not be legitimate reason to do so though.